# ssh command succeeds by itself, but when called in a bash script fails

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I have a couple of files for SSH

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 test  staff    94 Jun  5 20:26 login.sh
-r--------@ 1 test  staff  1696 May 23 18:41 aws-linux-machine-yahoo.pem
```

`login.sh` looks like this:

```
# login.sh
ssh -i aws-linux-machine-yahoo.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When I type the following I get:

```
$  ./login.sh
: nodename nor servname provided, or not knownx.xx.xx
```

However, if I type the `ssh` command directly in the terminal,

```
$  ssh -i aws-linux-machine-yahoo.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It succeeds.

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x login.sh` . Also are you surely running it from the same directory where the private key is?

Comment: Post content login.sh

Comment: @Douglas The content is in the question.

Comment: Thanks. The file, somehow, was a [dos] file.

Comment: I used the following `vim` command to fix

Comment: `set ff=unix`  and save  `:wq`